# How to move a Python Interpreter directory without reinstall or creating a virtual environment on Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I want to move my python interpreter from `D:\Softwares\Python` to `D:\Softwares\Python\Python3.7` which was originally installed in the first directory without reinstalling or creating a virtual environment on Windows.

I just simply created a new folder `Python3.7` and moved the files. Then I updated the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

If I run `python -v` in cmd, I can correctly see the version. But when I run `scrapy shell [url]`, there's an error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\softwares\python\python.exe"  "D:\Softwares\Python\Python3.7\Scripts\scrapy.exe" shell http://guba.eastmoney.com/list,cjpl.html': ???????????
```

**I know there's something wrong with my `python.exe` path, but I don't know how to fix it without reinstalling the interpreter.**

I'd appreciate it a lot for your help.

*note: I've already changed the environment variable path.*

Comment: Sounds like you need to reconfigure the Scrapy shell to use the interpreter in its new location.

Comment: I agree with you, I should search for the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. Just **reinstalling scrapy** works.